# Disallowed character when posting field name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue when posting fields like the following in codeigniter
`type="checkbox" name="test[some content]"`
Notice the space between [some content]. If there is no space it works fine, but I need it to have space.

Comment: I don't think you can have spaces in variable names in PHP

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will replace space with underscore. I thought it was allowed. Learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "disallowed character" problem in CodeIgniter it is probably due to the limitations in system/application/config/config.php. Check the "permitted_uri_chars" setting in that config file and add the characters you need.